# Use SSRS Expression to Open New Window / Tab from URL

Tags: reporting-services, expression, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2

I've looked at a couple of websites that explain how this works including:

[SQL Chick](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/8/22/opening-a-link-in-ssrs-within-a-new-window.html)

[Brian Knight](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/BrianKnight/ssis/972/ssrs-action-to-open-a-url-in-a-new-window)

But so far, I am not able to get the formatting correct to open the link in a new window.  Here is my expression that works, but doesn't open a new window:

```
="https://servicedesk.gooutdoorsvirginia.com/ImageProcessing/DocumentViewer.aspx?b=" & Fields!BatchID.Value & "&s=" & Fields!SeqNumber.Value & "&d=" & Cstr(Format(Fields!UploadDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")) & "&r=0"
```

I've tried a couple of variations to get this to work but nothing is working.  Would anyone be able to assist me in this endeavor?

Tested but does not work:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('https://servicedesk.gooutdoorsvirginia.com/ImageProcessing/DocumentViewer.aspx?b=" & Fields!BatchID.Value & "&s=" & Fields!SeqNumber.Value & "&d=" & Cstr(Format(Fields!UploadDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")) & "&r=0','_blank'))"


="javascript:void(window.open('"+ https://servicedesk.gooutdoorsvirginia.com/ImageProcessing/DocumentViewer.aspx?b=" & Fields!BatchID.Value & "&s=" & Fields!SeqNumber.Value & "&d=" & Cstr(Format(Fields!UploadDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")) & "&r=0" + "','_blank'))"
```

Comment: Have you been able to make it work with literals rather than substitution? This is what I do as soon as I have any issues trying to do variable substitution which use delimiters, quotes etc. which have to match, esp. if the purpose crosses a software boundary...This allows me to rule out (or catch) more fundamental issue, before starting into the more-difficult substitution work which makes my eyes bleed sometimes.

Comment: Your end result is a javascript command.  Have you checked the javascript console in the browser for any errors?

Comment: No - I guess I was not aware I could check.  I will see what if any errors I can find there.  And start with a literal expression as well and go from there.

Comment: I have successfully implemented it into one of my reports but i did this through the action on the textbox, I clicked on Go to URL and my expression was the following which looks like yours. ="javascript:void(window.open('https://servicedesk.gooutdoorsvirginia.com/ImageProcessing/DocumentViewer.aspx?b=" & Fields!BatchID.Value & "&s=" & Fields!SeqNumber.Value & "&d=" & Cstr(Format(Fields!UploadDate.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd")) & "&r=0','_blank'))"